# eventon select upcomming event with WP_Query

Tags: wordpress

How do I query only upcoming events and to look in them? `eventOn` does not give a function for that.

My code is:

```
    $events = new WP_Query(array(
      'post_type' => 'ajde_events',
      'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key' => 'evcal_srow',
          'value' => time(),
          'compare' => '>',
          'type' => 'numeric',
        )
      ),
    ));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be mindful of grammar and formatting. Not paying attention to spelling and punctuation can actually discourage answering; SO is a reference book in the making, and the community expects your help toward that goal. Many actually measure your effort by how well you asked. "[ask]", especially the links at the bottom, will help you understand.

Answer (score 2):

You're using start date to compare. It's incorrect way to get up coming events.

Change `'key' => 'evcal_srow'` to `'key' => 'evcal_erow'` will give correct results of upcoming events.

Comment: how to get a currunt active event?